# Only include sums that are checked

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I want to check if some of the columns are checked with `1` or not. If one or more columns are checked with `1`, take the total sum minus the sum that are checked.

Here's what I came up with at the moment: `=SUMIF(J3:J4; I27-(I3:I4); I27)`. That shows only `0`.

You can find a demo of this [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17jhpZ7oz0QF6rWlLi0LmyIzcJAOspYO2HoXKA01ztbw/edit?usp=sharing).

Why does it say `0` and how can I solve this problem? Do I use the right function (`SUMIF`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at you sheet, does this work for you:

```
=A6-SUMIF(B1:B3,"1",A1:A3)
```